# iOS cloned datetime input show no value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, datetime

With jQuery, I clone a LI containing filled input[type=datetime-local].

Works fine except on iOS.

I tested on Safari and Chrome for iOS, same result:
The cloned input do not show a value. If I trigger the UI, the starting datetime is the right one. If I loose focus, the input is still empty. If I change the value, then the value becomes visible.

Must be something with the UI of iOS.

Comment: a JSFiddle to demonstrate:

https://jsfiddle.net/CharlesStPierre/s7x773x3/

Answer (score 0):

I got my solution!

I change input type before appending to the container.

```
clone.find('input[type="datetime-local"]').attr('type', 'hidden');
```

After I append the clone to container, then change the type back.

```
$('#container').find('input[type="hidden"]).attr('type','datetime-local')
```

And that seems to revive the iOS datetime UI.